# Are herselves and himselves grammatically correct?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Suppose i have this sentence:

> **Ten women are looking at themselves.**

Since there's no a man in that group, can we replace themselves with "herselves"?

Comment: No, you cannot have 'herselves'. The plural of *herself/himself* is **themselves**. It's the same as [more than one] *her/him* → *them*.

Comment: No, this is not standard English at all.  It is just was wrong as writing, "I am looking at hers," when I am looking at multiple women.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.  "herselves" (and likewise "himselves") is not an actual English word.

The plural of "him" is "them".  The plural of "her" is also "them" (there is no distinction between a group of men or a group of women, they both use the same pronoun).  For singular pronouns, you use "-self", and for plural pronouns you use "-selves" (the singular/plural of both parts must always match), therefore:

- himself -- correct (singular ("him") + singular ("self"))
- herself -- correct (singular ("her") + singular ("self"))
- themselves -- correct (plural ("them") + plural ("selves"))
- himselves -- **incorrect** (singular ("him") + plural ("selves"))
- herselves -- **incorrect** (singular ("her") + plural ("selves"))
- themself -- **incorrect** (plural ("them") + singular ("self"))

The only situation I could imagine where you might legitimately "bend the rules" and say something like "herselves" is if you were writing some sort of sci-fi or fantasy story where one (single) person somehow had multiple bodies (multiple "selves"), and you wanted to emphasize in a particularly literary way that that one person was looking at multiples of herself, etc.  (But that only works because you are specifically describing (and drawing attention to) an abnormal condition which does not fit normal language rules)

Comment: "The only situation I could imagine where you might legitimately "bend the rules" and say something like "herselves" is if you were writing some sort of sci-fi or fantasy story" Alternately, I could totally believe a radical feminist might use "herselves" to refer a group of women. I don't know if any of them *have*, but I would be willing to believe that they *would*.